# Add where and and clause in connect with - ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, connect-by, hierarchical-query

I have a `table X` with columns `a, seq_no, dept_no, status` where `column a` contains values like `"1,2,3,4,5,6"`. To change the row to column I have used the query as:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT TO_NUMBER(regexp_substr(a,'[^,]+',1,level)) numbers
   FROM x 
CONNECT BY TO_NUMBER(regexp_substr(a,'[^,]+',1,level)) IS NOT NULL;
```

Here I want to add condition like where `dept_no is null and seq_no=1 and status='U'`.
How can I add the above mentioned condition.

Edit from comments:

I tried:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT TO_NUMBER(regexp_substr(a,'[^,]+',1,level)) numbers 
   FROM x 
  WHERE seq_no=1 
    AND status='U' 
  START WITH dept_no IS NULL 
CONNECT BY TO_NUMBER(regexp_substr(a,'[^,]+',1,level)) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: check examples given under  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm

Comment: I tried in the samy way, like                                                SELECT DISTINCT TO_NUMBER(regexp_substr(a,'[^,]+',1,level)) numbers
                                                   FROM x
                                                  WHERE seq_no=1
                                                    AND status='U'
                                                  START WITH dept_no IS NULL
                                                CONNECT BY TO_NUMBER(regexp_substr(a,'[^,]+',1,level)) IS NOT NULL;